# java.io.File cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, android

Приложение при запуске выдает ошибку:

```
java.io.File cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer.
```

Имеется список картинок с CD:

```
List mImg = new ArrayList(); 
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "ssdf/");
File[] filesArray = dir.listFiles();
mImg.addAll(Arrays.asList(filesArray));
```

Отображаем их:

```
holder.handleView.setImageResource((Integer) mImg.get(position));
```

Как я понимаю мой массив необходимо привести к массиву `Integer`?
Как это осуществляется?

P.S. - приложение работает если создаю массив из обьектов `drawable`.

Comment: Сообщение довольно ясное. В этом выражении (Integer) mImg.get(position) вы пытаетесь привести объект типа File к типу Integer, и компилятор сообщает, что такое преобразование невозможно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В метод `setImageResource(int resId)` передается идентификатор ресурса типа `int`, Вы же пытаетесь туда передать объект типа `File`.

Если Ваша коллекция состоит из объектов `File` (которые представляют собой изображения), то вывести эти изображения в `ImageView handleView` Вы можете следующим образом:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImg.get(position).getAbsolutePath());
holder.handleView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

**Замечание №1:**

Не делайте вот так:

```
List mImg = new ArrayList();
```

Создавайте явно типизированную коллекцию, дабы избежать проблем в дальнейшем:

```
List<File> mImg = new ArrayList();
```

**Замечание №2:**

Нет никакой необходимости хранить в адаптере список `List<File>`. Рациональнее будет хранить просто список путей до файлов (а еще рациональнее будет [кэшировать сами `bitmap`'-ы](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) и использовать что-нибудь типа `Picasso`, но это уже совсем другая история).

**UPD**.

Подробнее про хранение путей:

Создаете список `mImagesPaths`, в котором будут хранится абсолютные пути до файлов, находящихся в заданной директории:

```
List<String> mImagesPaths = new ArrayList();
File[] files  = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "ssdf/").listFiles();

for(File file : files){
    if(file.isFile()){
        mImagesPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

Далее в адаптере отображаете их:

```
holder.handleView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImagesPaths.get(position)));
```

Решение, наверное, не лучшее, но все же.

Comment: подскажите про хранение путей до файлов)

Comment: @evb, Смотрите **UPD**.

Comment: Про кэширование - ведь можно просто использовать что-то типа Picasso , или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @evb, Не ошибаетесь, можно. Но информация о том, как это работает изнутри, никогда не помешает.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Ваш пример действительно работает. Но у меня как у новичка постоянно возникают проблемы) Picasso не загружает изображения .  mPicasso.load(mImagesPaths.get(position)).fit().centerCrop().error(R.drawable.ic_launcher).into(holder.handleView);

Comment: @evb, А что при этом происходит? Ошибки? или?

Comment: Список загружается пустым, спустя секунду появляется картинка заданная в error(). При этом жутко тормозит

Comment: @evb, Навскидку сложно что-то сказать. Лучше создайте новый вопрос, подробно описав проблему.